# boost variant: get reference to the variant by its type

Tags: c++, boost, variant

Suppose there is

```
boost::variant<int, std::string> v;
```

How do I get a reference `x` of type `std::string &` that could be used like

```
x = "abc";
```

and would have a behaviour equivalent to

```
v = "abc";
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::string& x = boost::get<std::string>(v);`

Comment: Can you get a reference without assignment?

Comment: @thc boost::get returns a reference by default.